# API Authorization Tool

Tags: api, security, authorization, keycloak, rbac

I'm working on an application with RESTful API endpoints that needs proper authorization security using an RBAC system. So far, I've looked into **Keycloak**. It looks promising at first but doesn't support granular authorization control of an endpoint, which is a hard requirement. For example, if I have the endpoint `/object/<object:id>`, a list of object IDs `[1,2,3,4]` and a test user, there's no way to restrict the test user to only have access to object IDs `[1,2]` but not `[3,4]` for the same endpoint. It seems the user will have access to all the IDs or none. Perhaps this can be accomplished by customizing or extending the base Keycloak server but there isn't enough documentation on the Keycloak website on how to do so.

I've done a search for other RBAC permissions systems but haven't been able to find much. Are there any authorization systems out there that can accomplish this?

Comment: What data in the user context would you use to define what an user can access ?

Comment: In the current system system that I'm trying to replace, I'm keep tracking of what a user can access using the user's ID and various DB tables. So I think I'd continue using those tables for the same purpose for a new system

Answer (score 0):

> but doesn't support granular authorization control of an endpoint

Check out Auth0's Fine Grained Authorization solution: https://docs.fga.dev/. (Disclaimer: I am employed by Auth0).

In your specific case you would need to create an authorization model like

```
type object
   relations
      define reader as self
```

And then add the following tuples in the FGA store using the [Write API](https://docs.fga.dev/integration/update-tuples):

```
(user:test, relation:reader, object:1)
(user:test, relation:reader, object:2)
```

Then, in your API, you would do something like this:

```js
const { Auth0FgaApi } = require('@auth0/fga')

const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const fgaClient = new Auth0FgaApi({
     storeId: process.env.FGA_STORE_ID,  // Fill this in!
     clientId: process.env.FGA_CLIENT_ID,  // Fill this in!
     clientSecret: process.env.FGA_CLIENT_SECRET // Fill this in!
});

app.get('/objects/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { allowed } = await fgaClient.check({
            tuple_key: {
                user: req.query.user,
                relation: 'reader',
                object: "object:" + req.params.id
            }
        });
        if (!allowed) {
            res.status(403).send("Unauthorized!")
        } else {
            res.status(200).send("Authorized!")
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error)
    }

});

const port = 3000
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```